# How to prove ∃x∃yA↔∃y∃xA in intuitionistic first-order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, intuitionistic-logic

In this logic primitives include ∃ ∀ → ∧ ∨ ⊥. ~A is A→⊥. Substitution of $a$ for $x$ in A is denoted as A$_x$[$a$]. Rules of inference are modus ponens and ∀-generalization. Deduction theorem is usable. Axioms related to quantifiers are

Q1.∀$x$A→A$_x$[$a$] when $a$ is free for $x$ in A

Q2.A$_x$[$a$]→∃$x$A when $a$ is free for $x$ in A

Q3.∀$x$(A→B)→(A→∀$x$B) when $x$ isn't free in A

Q4.∀$x$(B→A)→(∃$x$B→A) when $x$ isn't free in A

Proving things about ∀ is easier for me, because there are axioms and rules to eliminate and reintroduce ∀. I find difficulty on dealing with ∃. There are no rules to get rid of ∃ and no theorems like (~A→~B)→(B→A) and ~~A→A to convert ∃ into ∀.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rule 4 is the rule to get rid of $\exists$.  It could be written  $$\dfrac{\forall x (B \to A),\quad\exists x B}{A}$$, and it should be restrained with both $x$ not free in $A$ and $x$ not free in any premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#IntFirOrdPreLog) :

1) $A \to ∃y∃xA$ --- Ax.Q2 twice

2) $∃x∃yA \to ∃y∃xA$ --- from 1) by $∃$-Elimination: From $A(x) → C$, where $x$ does not occur free in $C$, conclude $∃xA(x) → C$.

With your rules, you have to use $∀$-Introduction ("$∀$-generalization") on 1) followed by *modus ponens* with Ax.Q4 twice.